# How can I display dash or stars when entering my password?

Tags: python

I have created a simple login program using python, I would like it to display stars or dashes when the user enters a password instead of displaying numbers.

Comment: You'll have to read and react to one character at a time. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to avoid echoing the input - you can use a python standard library called [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#module-getpass)- in it, there is a function called `getpass` which hides the user input:

```
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
```

Note that `getpass` requires a proper terminal, so it can turn off the echoing of typed characters.

If you wish to display stars when the user enters a password, you can install the [pwinput](https://pypi.org/project/pwinput/) module:

```
pip install pwinput
```

For example:

```
>>> pwinput.pwinput()
Password: ********
'password'
```

You can also change the mask character:

```
>>> pwinput.pwinput(mask='X') # Change the mask character.
Password: XXXXXXXX
'password'
```

And you can also change the prompt:

```
>>> pwinput.pwinput(prompt='PW: ', mask='*') # Change the prompt.
PW: ********
'password'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PWInput` module is able to display characters as you type.

```sh
>>> import pwinput
>>> pwinput.pwinput()  # Show * for each typed character.
Password: *********
'swordfish'
>>> pwinput.pwinput(prompt='PW: ')  # Show a custom prompt.
PW: *********
'swordfish'
>>> pwinput.pwinput(mask='X')  # Show a different character when user types.
Password: XXXXXXXXX
'swordfish'
>>> pwinput.pwinput(mask='') # Don't show anything when user types (falls back and calls getpass.getpass()).
Password:
'swordfish'
```

Have a look! https://pypi.org/project/pwinput/1.0.1/